# Why spark map produces different result as RDD when input element converted to int/string in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm just trying to create a pairRDD using map and my input file contains 3 lines of numbers like below,

*12

34

36*

and having it in val **lines**.

Below line of code,

```
val pairRDD=lines.map(x => (x(0).toInt,x(1).toInt))
```

produces

(49,50)
(51,52)
(51,54)

as result

### &

```
val pairRDD=lines.map(x => (x(0),x(1)))
```

produces

(1,2)
(3,4)
(3,6)
as result.

so, the only difference between 2 lines of code is, I'm converting to Int before mapping it but, however, I have just numbers in input files unchanged.

could someone help me to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference comes from how scala *Char.toInt* works, firstly each line is a string, and indexing a string, you get a character, the Char.toInt method gets the ASCII value of that character, so '1' is 49, for instance:

```
val x = "12"
// x: String = 12

x(0)
// res12: Char = 1

x(0).toInt
// res13: Int = 49
```

To convert the digit literally to an Int, you can convert it to String, then to Int:

```
x(0).toString.toInt
// res15: Int = 1
```

Comment: You could also use `x(0).asDigit`